# Xcode 5 console application segfaults only when launched via finder

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, segmentation-fault, osx-mavericks

I've written a console application in c++ in Xcode. When launched via finder (by double clicking the executable in the build directory) I get a terminal window saying "Segmentation fault: 11".

However, when I open terminal, navigate to the folder and run the executable by doing ./"executable name" the program runs fine. Also runs fine when launched in an instance of lldb in terminal.

Why is this?

Crash log from console to app. below:

```
Process:         UDPServer [3640]
Path:            /Users/USER/Desktop/*/UDPServer
Identifier:      UDPServer
Version:         0
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [3637]
Responsible:     Terminal [3047]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-08-21 09:38:55.153 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  50B9AAFB-D335-BAF0-BE59-B5EDE60DC6A3

Sleep/Wake UUID: 5133BBF8-BBC6-4207-A12E-040C0E38E283

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000101b6a000-0000000101b74000 [   40K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Desktop/*

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   UDPServer                       0x0000000101b6f70e main + 230 (main.cpp:34)
1   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff85f245fd start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fca0b500130  rbx: 0x00007fff74d5f2f8  rcx: 0x2e3836312e323931  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00007fca0b50014e  rsi: 0x00007fff5e095b2e  rbp: 0x00007fff5e095b90  rsp: 0x00007fff5e0956b0
   r8: 0x000000000000000d   r9: 0x00007fca0b500000  r10: 0x000000000000000d  r11: 0xffffffcaad46a620
  r12: 0x00007fff74f79420  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x0000000101b6f70e  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x101b6a000 -        0x101b73fff +UDPServer (0) <15B3E381-DAAC-34FC-A83D-5A6206126BE8> /Users/USER/Desktop/*/UDPServer
       0x101b89000 -        0x101b91ff7 +liboscpack.so (0) <1C20B5CF-B522-3D36-8B2D-B324AD4FCA62> /Users/USER/Desktop/*/liboscpack.so
       0x101ba0000 -        0x101c31fff +libboost_regex.dylib (0) <1A50E6A0-A616-3091-A6D1-4B4E8590A27F> /Users/USER/Desktop/*/libboost_regex.dylib
       0x101cbb000 -        0x101cbdff3 +libboost_system.dylib (0) <D55FA09E-42A9-3C49-836F-EF08DD5B42DF> /Users/USER/Desktop/*/libboost_system.dylib
    0x7fff6c0c2000 -     0x7fff6c0f5817  dyld (239.4) <042C4CED-6FB2-3B1C-948B-CAF2EE3B9F7A> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff84bf1000 -     0x7fff84bf6ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <78DCC358-2FC1-302E-B395-0155B47CB547> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff84d0b000 -     0x7fff84d0cff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (63) <FB856CD1-2AEA-3907-8E9B-1E54B6827F82> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff84fbe000 -     0x7fff84fc4ff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (24.90.1) <3C3D3DA8-32B9-3243-98EC-D89B9A1670B3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff851e9000 -     0x7fff85210ffb  libsystem_info.dylib (449.1.3) <7D41A156-D285-3849-A2C3-C04ADE797D98> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff85613000 -     0x7fff85665fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <4F68DFC5-2077-39A8-A449-CAC5FDEE7BDE> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff8575e000 -     0x7fff8590bf27  libobjc.A.dylib (551.1) <AD7FD984-271E-30F4-A361-6B20319EC73B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff859cf000 -     0x7fff859d0ff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <E6BCC031-4342-318C-A1AD-A8E9AEAE716F> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff85c2e000 -     0x7fff85c2ffff  libunc.dylib (28) <62682455-1862-36FE-8A04-7A6B91256438> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff85c58000 -     0x7fff85c5fffb  libcopyfile.dylib (103.92.1) <CF29DFF6-0589-3590-834C-82E2316612E8> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff85c96000 -     0x7fff85c97ff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <4CDB0F7B-C0AF-3424-BC39-495696F0DB1E> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff85d60000 -     0x7fff85d7bff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (23.10.1) <A695B4E4-38E9-332E-A772-29D31E3F1385> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff85f21000 -     0x7fff85f24ff7  libdyld.dylib (239.4) <A1273A02-4928-3BAC-A846-6C069DC1A0A6> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8655d000 -     0x7fff86561ff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (93.90.3) <337946FC-B2E1-3DFA-A8B5-30DA8D584D75> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff86562000 -     0x7fff865ebff7  libsystem_c.dylib (997.90.3) <6FD3A400-4BB2-3B95-B90C-BE6E9D0D78FA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff8660a000 -     0x7fff86633ff7  libc++abi.dylib (49.1) <21A807D3-6732-3455-B77F-743E9F916DF0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8665a000 -     0x7fff86812ffb  libicucore.A.dylib (511.34) <616A65D6-3F20-3EAB-8CA8-273AD890261C> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff86813000 -     0x7fff86842fd2  libsystem_m.dylib (3047.16) <B7F0E2E4-2777-33FC-A787-D6430B630D54> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff87206000 -     0x7fff8720fff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (121) <52571EC3-6894-37E4-946E-064B021ED44E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff878c1000 -     0x7fff8790ffff  libcorecrypto.dylib (161.1) <F3973C28-14B6-3006-BB2B-00DD7F09ABC7> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff891cc000 -     0x7fff893b1fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 855.17) <729BD6DA-1F63-3E72-A148-26F21EBF52BB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff893b2000 -     0x7fff893b3ffb  libremovefile.dylib (33) <3543F917-928E-3DB2-A2F4-7AB73B4970EF> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8a7f4000 -     0x7fff8a7f6ff7  libquarantine.dylib (71) <7A1A2BCB-C03D-3A25-BFA4-3E569B2D2C38> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff8b547000 -     0x7fff8b54ffff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (522.92.1) <17B03FFD-92C5-3282-9981-EBB28B456207> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff8c3e8000 -     0x7fff8c42aff7  libauto.dylib (185.5) <F45C36E8-B606-3886-B5B1-B6745E757CA8> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff8c4fb000 -     0x7fff8c522ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (241.3) <8B1E1F1D-A5CC-3BAE-8B1E-ABC84337A364> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff8c523000 -     0x7fff8c52aff8  liblaunch.dylib (842.92.1) <A40A0C7B-3216-39B4-8AE0-B5D3BAF1DA8A> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8c561000 -     0x7fff8c563ff3  libsystem_configuration.dylib (596.15) <4998CB6A-9D54-390A-9F57-5D1AC53C135C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff8c7cd000 -     0x7fff8c7cefff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (278.11.1) <0D0B13EA-6B7A-3AC8-BE60-B548543BEB77> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8c81e000 -     0x7fff8c823fff  libmacho.dylib (845) <1D2910DF-C036-3A82-A3FD-44FF73B5FF9B> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff8c825000 -     0x7fff8c829ff7  libcache.dylib (62) <BDC1E65B-72A1-3DA3-A57C-B23159CAAD0B> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff8d311000 -     0x7fff8d335fff  libxpc.dylib (300.90.2) <AB40CD57-F454-3FD4-B415-63B3C0D5C624> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff8d496000 -     0x7fff8d4b0fff  libdispatch.dylib (339.92.1) <C4E4A18D-3C3B-3C9C-8709-A4270D998DE7> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8e58d000 -     0x7fff8e594ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (53.1.4) <AB498556-B555-310E-9041-F67EC9E00E2C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff90152000 -     0x7fff90159fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <4CD916B2-1B17-362A-B403-EF24A1DAC141> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff904dd000 -     0x7fff904ddff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <3AA8D85D-CF00-3BD3-A5A0-E28E1A32A6D8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff9090d000 -     0x7fff9091eff7  libz.1.dylib (53) <42E0C8C6-CA38-3CA4-8619-D24ED5DD492E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff91aec000 -     0x7fff91af6fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60049) <8C4F0CA0-389C-3EDC-B155-E62DD2187E1D> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff92113000 -     0x7fff92124ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (217.1.4) <655FB343-52CF-3E2F-B14D-BEBF5AAEF94D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff92846000 -     0x7fff92862ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2422.110.17) <873931CE-D1AF-3596-AADB-D2E63C9AB29F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 76355
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 795

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=76.1M resident=112.7M(148%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=16777216.0T(23109604212736%)
Writable regions: Total=26.5M written=172K(1%) resident=236K(1%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=26.2M(99%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             18.2M
MALLOC (admin)                       16K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
__DATA                             1108K
__LINKEDIT                         66.8M
__TEXT                             9540K
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             159.9M
```

My main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//    if(argc != 2){
//        std::cout << "Useage: UDPSever <videohub ip> \n";
//        return 1;
//    }
    std::string videoHubIp;
    std::cout << "Enter VideoHub IP Address" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> videoHubIp;
    std::cin.ignore();

    HRESULT result = NULL;
    IVideohub *videohub;
    IVideohubDiscovery *videoHubDiscovery = CreateVideohubDiscoveryInstance(NULL);

    CFStringRef deviceAddress = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, videoHubIp.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
//    CFStringRef deviceAddress = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, argv[1], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    if((result = videoHubDiscovery->ConnectTo(deviceAddress, 10000, &videohub) != S_OK)){ //this is line 34
        std::cout << "Failed to connect, check network settings..." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    OSCHandler osc(videohub);
    udp_server server(io, osc);
    io.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are there any system logs about that (see *Console.app*)?

Comment: Crash log now added. I'm not sure how to read that but 'Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000' sticks out?

Comment: You crashed at line 34 of "main.cpp", in `main`, dereferencing a null pointer. If I had to guess: the program doesn't properly handle the case of getting no arguments (i.e. `argc` is 1).

Comment: Indeed; show us the start of `main()`.

Comment: I've added the main function and commented line 34 (the if statement just over half way down).

Comment: OK it looks like you need to validate that an address was specified via `cin`.  I am not near a Mac at the moment so I cannot test the behaviour of Finder when invoking a command line executable that reads from stdin.

Comment: I guess its something to do with creating the videoHubDiscovery instance but then it runs fine under a debugger. CreateVideoHubDiscovery depends on a manufacturers library which is shipped as a .bundle and loaded using CFBundleCreate, perhaps its not being loaded when launched from finder?

Comment: I should add, the segfault occurs immediately after I enter the IP address and hit return.

Comment: Yeah more validation would not go amiss; for example `if (!deviceAddress) { cout << "Eeek\n"; << exit(1); }`. Same goes for `videoHubDiscovery`.  Logging would also improve your chances of maintaining this code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when a program is launched via Finder it's working directory is set to '/' rather than the directory that the executable was launched from. This was causing a segfault in my program as I was trying to load a library in a relative location to the executable. I still need to figure out how to do that but at least the cause of the error is now known.

Thanks for suggestions regarding logging and validation, through which I was able to figure out what was going on.

Edit: in case anyone else has this problem, I found a solution here:

http://codemunch.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/do-not-make-assumptions-on-current.html

Comment: One way to solve that is to get the path of the executable from `argv[0]`, strip off the last element and use that to `chdir()` into the directory.  No need for a Foundation method in order to do that.

Comment: I had though of that but sometimes argv[0] only contains the executable name (say if the program was run in terminal by typing ./<executable name>). At least thats how it is on my system.

Comment: Exactly; so `./exename` with the executable name stripped leaves `.` which will also work.

Comment: Still won't work in all cases. For instance finder sets working directory to "/" so using "." won't help. The most robust way will be to get the full path to the executable.

Comment: No, it will work.  The current working directory is not relevant as you are going to set it.  If you want the current working directory to be the same as the executable file then use the methods I have mentioned.

Comment: See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/trojanfoe/478f5604b3328a6e12f6) for an example.